# Why clearing the arraylist is clearing the other arraylist even after the completely the assigning the value?

Tags: java, xml, arraylist, xml-parsing

I have created a two list. First list is of some class type(Syncgroupset) and second list is arraylist of type string. This syncgroupset class contain getter and setter for the arraylist of type list.

I will be parsing the xml and copying the parsed values to the list type of class(syncgroupset).

Please find the xml as below.

```
<syncgroupsettings>
        <syncgroupset id = "sgMS" labelid = "lblMS" enabled = "YES" default = "OFF">
            <syncgroup syncgroupname = "VISITS"/>
            <syncgroup syncgroupname = "CUSTOMERS"/>
        </syncgroupset>

        <syncgroupset id = "sgAS" labelid = "lblAS" enabled = "YES" default = "ON">
            <syncgroup syncgroupname = "SALESDOCS"/>
            <syncgroup syncgroupname = "ANALYTICS"/>
        </syncgroupset>
    </syncgroupsettings>
```

Please find the code as below

```
public List<Syncgroupset> parse(XmlPullParser parser) {
        String id = "";
        String synlabelid="";
        String enabled = "";
        String default1 = "";
        String syngroupname = "";

        List<Syncgroupset> mysynset = new ArrayList<Syncgroupset>();

        try {
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();

            List<String> mysyname = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("labels"))
                        {
                            skip(parser);

                        }else
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("syncgroupsettings")) {
                            // do nothing
                        }else
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("syncgroupset")) {
                            syncgroupset = new Syncgroupset();
                            id = parser.getAttributeValue(ns,"id");
                            synlabelid = parser.getAttributeValue(ns,"labelid");
                            enabled = parser.getAttributeValue(ns,"enabled");
                            default1 = parser.getAttributeValue(ns,"default");
                            syncgroupset.setLabelid(synlabelid);
                            syncgroupset.setEnabled(enabled);
                            syncgroupset.setDefault(default1);
                            syncgroupset.setId(id);
                            mysynset.add(syncgroupset);
                        }else
                        if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("syncgroup"))
                        {
                            syngroupname = parser.getAttributeValue(ns,"syncgroupname");
                            mysyname.add(syngroupname);
                        }
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if (tagname.equals("syncgroupset")) {
                            mysynset.get(mysynset.size() - 1).setSyncgroup(mysyname);
                            mysyname.clear();
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mysynset;
    }
```

When i encounter the syncgroup tag, i will be copying the values to other list of type string. I'm not adding syncgroup value to list of type class here only.

When i encounter the end tag of syncgroupsetting, then only i'm adding list of type string to the list of type class by replacing.

Then i'm clearing the list of type string. When i do like this, it is even clearing the list which is inside the list of class. Could you please let me know where i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `Syncgroupset` keeps a shallow copy of the list you pass to it with `setSyncgroup(list)`. That's why `list.clear()` affects the `Syncgroupset` too.

Change this line:

> ```
> mysynset.get(mysynset.size() - 1).setSyncgroup(mysyname);
> ```

To this:

```
mysynset.get(mysynset.size() - 1).setSyncgroup(new ArrayList<String>(mysyname));
```

That way, it will be not `mysyname` passed to it,
but a fresh new list with all elements of `mysyname` copied,
and then `mysyname.clear()` can in no way affect the list passed with that `setSyncgroup` call.

Comment: Hey Janos, Thanks a lot. you saved my day and also you made me to realize the concept of clearing the arraylist perfectly.